# Parallel compression folder, best solution in c#

Tags: c#

I need to compress more folder at same time in different archivie to goes more quikly. 
I tried to use a main backgroundworker and from this I did a for cycle to start other backgroundworker for each folder. I notice that the backgroundworker starts all at same time but not works together what is the best way to do a parallel archive?what you suggest?
to create the archive I use the zipforge library

```
DoWork of the main backgroundworker
if (Directory.Exists(destination))
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.No)
            {
                goto EXIT_UTENTE;
            }
            else
            {
                bool finish = false;
                int j = 1;

                string dest_appoggio = destination;

                do
                {
                    dest_appoggio = destination + "_" + j;

                    if (Directory.Exists(dest_appoggio))
                    {
                        j++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        destination = dest_appoggio;
                        dataprogressiva = data + "_" + j;
                        finish = true;
                    }
                }
                while (finish == false);
            }
        }

        destinationdefault = destination;

        var row_list1 = GetDataGridRows(dgwRobot);

        int riga = -1;

        foreach (DataGridRow single_row1 in row_list1)
        {
            bool rowselected = false;
            single_row1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { rowselected = single_row1.IsSelected; }));


            if (rowselected == true)
            {
                riga = single_row1.GetIndex();
                var robotProcessed = false;

                while (!robotProcessed)
                {
                    for (var threadNum = 0; threadNum < MaxBackupContemporanei; threadNum++)
                    {
                        if (!threadArray[threadNum].IsBusy)
                        {
                            threadArray[threadNum].RunWorkerAsync(riga);

                            robotProcessed = true;

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        bool bwTerminati = false;

        while (!bwTerminati)
        {
            for (var threadNum = 0; threadNum < MaxBackupContemporanei; threadNum++)
            {
                if (threadArray[threadNum].IsBusy)
                {
                    bwTerminati = false;
                    threadNum = MaxBackupContemporanei;
                }
                else
                {
                    bwTerminati = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Paolo, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you expand on what's happening? When you say that they're not working together, do you mean they the tasks are all initialized at the same time, but then each task ends up being executed sequentially?

Comment: Aside, you may want to look into [`Parallel.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke?view=netframework-4.8) here; that may simplify some of your logic.

Comment: The background are all inizialized at the same time but they start radom.

Comment: For example the first after 15/20 second the third when finish the first start the second and so on. I notice also the ram memory incrise very much without degrase the one background as finished the job, also if I use one background for each backups. I think I have some problems in the logic.
Isn't easy to exmplain the logic, I have a datagrid with all the row, one row is one backup that have the source directory where take the backup and copy to destination in a zip file or normal directory. I put all the code here -> [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/pc8kq9nsb3chn6z/Backup.7z?dl=0